# Power BI measures format not showing for whole numbers when using calculated groups

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services

I have started leveraging the power of calculated groups on Azure Analysis Services and immediately noticed some weird behavior on Power BI.
Some of the measures did not had the right format even though correctly specified on the measures and the calculated groups are using the selected measure format.

The behavior seems to be present only on whole number formatted measures based on distinct counts.
Measures based on sum of decimal columns seems to be presenting the right format.

Anyone facing the same behavior?

Comment: Same issue here. It appeared recently. Microsoft bug?

Comment: This issue is identified by Microsoft and should be release during August 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was already fixed by Microsoft.

Thank you